# How would I do a pop on a PG::Result in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, pg

Running a pop on a result set from a pgsql database I get:

```
undefined method `pop' for #<PG::Result:0x0000000273dc08>
```

I want to get the first 5 of that result set, do something with it, then do it again with the next 5.  I don't want to run my query twice as it is a fairly long query.

How would I do this in ruby?

I am running ruby 2.1 and rails 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PG::Result` is `Enumerable` so you could just use [`each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) on it:

```
your_pg_result.each_slice(5) do |array|
  # array is at most five rows from the result set
  # on each iteration so do whatever needs to be done
end
```

If you need to differentiate the iterations then throw a [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) into the mix:

```
your_pg_result.each_slice(5).with_index do |array, i|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Though @user4703663 answer was closer to the question, this answer   is a closer fix to the problem I was attempting to solve.  Thanks  to both of you for your contributions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `PGResult` is not an array, it is an object. You need to convert it to an array with the `to_a` method.

Comment: And hope that the result set fits into memory. It'd be better/safer/more scalable to iterate over it or retrieve the data in chunks.